# Increment through two vectors to add parts of each to a new vector (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, while-loop, append

I have two vectors `colour` and `angle`.

I wish to create a new vector `F` which is made up as follows:

First 16 elements of `angle`, followed by first 512 elements of `colour`, followed by second 16 elements of `angle`, followed by second 512 elements of `colour` etc...

I have tried to implement this using two `while` loops as shown below.

```
colour = reshape(col,1,[]);
angle = reshape(ang,1,[]);
j = 1;
i = 1;
F = [];
while i <= 64
    F = [F angle(i:i+15)];
    i = i + 16;
    while j <= 2048
        F = [F colour(j:j+511)];
    end
    j = j + 512;
end
```

This is not working as I intended. Could anyone please help me with this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would solve it:

```
c2=reshape(colour,16,[]);
a2=reshape(angle,512,[]);
merged=[c2;a2];
merged=merged(:);
```

Using the reshape operation, it's first column of c2, then first column of a2, then second coumn of c2 etc...

Comment: This would be my first approach too

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If you saw my comment previous to my edit please ignore it...I made a silly mistake! This works great